# How is the intercept computed in the GLM fit?

Tags: r, formula, intercept

I have been reading the [code](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/glm.R) used by R to fit a *generalized linear model* (GLM), since the source-code of R is freely available. The algorithm used is called *iteratively reweighted least squares* (IRLS), which is a fairly documented algorithm. For each iteration, there is a call to a Fortran function to solve the weighted least squares problem.

From the end-user's viewpoint, for a logistic regression for instance, a call in R looks just like this:

```
y <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
x <- rnorm(100)
glm(y~x, family=binomial)$coefficients
```

And if you do not want to use a *intercept*, either of these calls is okay:

```
glm(y~x-1, family=binomial)$coefficients
glm(y~x+0, family=binomial)$coefficients
```

However, I cannot manage to understand how the *formula*, i.e. `y~x` or `y~x-1`, is making sense in the code and being understood as for whether to use an intercept or not. I was looking for a part of the code where a column of ones would be bound to `x`, but it seems there is none.

As far as I have read, the boolean intercept which appears in the function called `glm.fit` is not the same as the intercept which I am referring to. And it is the same for the *offset*.

The documentation about `glm` and `glm.fit` is [here](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/stats/html/glm.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking in the wrong place. Usually, `model.matrix()` is called first in the fitting functions:

```
> D <- data.frame(x1=1:4, x2=4:1)
> model.matrix(~ x1 + x2, D)
  (Intercept) x1 x2
1           1  1  4
2           1  2  3
3           1  3  2
4           1  4  1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2
> model.matrix(~ x1 + x2 -1 , D)
  x1 x2
1  1  4
2  2  3
3  3  2
4  4  1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 2
>
```

and it is the output of `model.matrix()` which is passed down to Fortran.  That is the case for `lm()` and other model fitters.

For `glm()`, it is different and only `model.frame()` is called which *does not* add an intercept column.  Why that is so has to do with the difference between *generalized* linear models and standard linear models and beyond the scope of this posting.

Comment: is the last paragraph of this answer actually correct? `glm.fit` takes a model matrix `x` which is exactly the same as in `lm.fit` ...

Comment: It's been a few years since I answered that but I seem to recall looking that up in the code. I could of course be wrong on any aspect of it...